# Disable field that belongs to home page from admin page

Tags: javascript, html

I salute you! This is my first question here. I am working on a web project and I am a starter in learning PHP. I need help with this scenario: I have a home page where users can fill some input fields. I also created a page for an admin which is currently blank because I am working on developing its functionalities. The main functionality I would like it to have is the following one: As an admin, what if I don't want to let the users fill one of the fields? Basically I want to disable that field. I am not sure how I am supposed to do this! Any piece of advice/code is much appreciated! Thank you!

I will let a piece of code from the home page:

```
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="body-column">
            <form method="post" action="submitFormHome.php">
                <div>
                    <label for="year">Select year:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="year" id="year"/>
                        <script>
                            viewHandler.updateUIValueFromCookie(chartData.idYear)
                            $('input[name="year"]').amsifySuggestags({
                                type : 'bootstrap',
                                //suggestions: getSuggestionsForColumn(columnCountry),
                                suggestions: ["1970", "2015", "2016"],
                                whiteList: true
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="sex">Select sex:</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="sex" id="sex"/>
                        <script>
                            viewHandler.updateUIValueFromCookie(chartData.idSex)
                            $('input[name="sex"]').amsifySuggestags({
                                type : 'bootstrap',
                                //suggestions: getSuggestionsForColumn(columnCountry),
                                suggestions: ["Male", "Female", "Both sexes"],
                                whiteList: true
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="country">Select country</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" id="country"/>
                        <script>
                            viewHandler.updateUIValueFromCookie(chartData.idCountry)
                            $('input[name="country"]').amsifySuggestags({
                                type : 'bootstrap',
                                //suggestions: getSuggestionsForColumn(columnCountry),
                                suggestions: ["Romania", "Bulgaria", "China", "Germany", "Afghanistan"],
                                whiteList: true
                            })
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="region">Select region</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region" id="region"/>
                        <script>
                            viewHandler.updateUIValueFromCookie(chartData.idRegion)
                            $('input[name="region"]').amsifySuggestags({
                                type : 'bootstrap',
                                //suggestions: getSuggestionsForColumn(columnCountry),
                                suggestions: ["Europe", "Africa", "Americas"],
                                whiteList: true
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="filterButton" onclick="filter()">Filter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

For instance, I want to disable the "Select year" field. I know the code looks a bit messy, the main idea is that when a user fills the blank space, basically he modifies a chart. Is like he filters some data. I think I should mention it too.

I add the backend too:

```
/**
 * Model
 * Handles all the data
 */

 class Miscellaneous {
    constructor() {
        this.MIME_TYPE = "image/png"
        this.testFileName = "text.csv"
        this.dataFileName = "data.csv"
        this.mainChartNameId = "mainChart"
    }
}

class ColorManager {
    constructor() {
        this.colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#00FFFF", "#FF00FF"]
        // red        green      blue       yellow     cyan       magenta
        this.colorsIterator = 0

        this.borderColors = ["#00FF00", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00", "#0000FF", "#FF00FF", "#00FFFF"]
        //green       red        yellow      blue      magenta     cyan
        this.borderColorsIterator = 0
    }

    // We explicitly use 'ch' instead of 'this' because when we call
    // 'getXColors', a new function will be created that has no connection to 'this'
    iterateColorsAndIncrement(ch) {
        let valueToReturn = ch.colors.colorsIterator
        if(ch.colors.colorsIterator < ch.colors.length - 1) {
            ch.colors.colorsIterator++
        } else {
            ch.colors.colorsIterator = 0
        }
        return valueToReturn
    }

    iterateBorderColorsAndIncrement(ch) {
        let valueToReturn = ch.borderColorsIterator
        if(ch.borderColorsIterator < ch.borderColors.length - 1) {
            ch.borderColorsIterator++
        } else {
            ch.borderColorsIterator = 0
        }
        return valueToReturn
    }

    getXColors(x, func, ch) {
        const colorsList = [];
        while(x > 0) {
            colorsList.push(ch.colors[func(ch)])
            x = x-1
        }
        return colorsList
    }

}

class ChartData {
    constructor() {
        // The order in the csv files is as stands:
        // Location___Country___Year___Sex___Value
        // 0          1         2      3     4
        this.selectedRegion = ["Europe"] // getCookie for list
        this.selectedCountry = ["Romania", "Bulgaria", "Germany"] // getCookie for list
        this.selectedYear = ["2016"] // getCookie for list
        this.selectedSex = ["Male"] // getCookie for list

        this.columnRegion = 0
        this.columnCountry = 1
        this.columnYear = 2
        this.columnSex = 3
        this.columnValue = 4

        this.idRegion = "region"
        this.idCountry = "country"
        this.idYear = "year"
        this.idSex = "sex"
        this.idValue = "value"
    }
}

/**
 * Controller
 * Handles all the data manipulation
 */

class ChartHandler {
    constructor() {}

    updateType(imageFormatBox) {
        alert(imageFormatBox.value)
        switch(imageFormatBox.value) {
            case "CSV":
                misc.MIME_TYPE = "text/csv"
                break;
            case "PNG":
                misc.MIME_TYPE = "image/png"
                break;
            case "SCV":
                misc.MIME_TYPE = "image/scv"
                break;
            default:
                // code block
        }
        alert(misc.MIME_TYPE)
    }

    saveChart(chartId) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(chartId);
        const imageURL = canvas.toDataURL(this.misc.MIME_TYPE);

        const dlLink = document.createElement('a');
        dlLink.download = "graph";
        dlLink.href = imageURL;
        dlLink.dataset.downloadurl = [misc.MIME_TYPE, dlLink.download, dlLink.href].join(':');

        document.body.appendChild(dlLink);
        dlLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(dlLink);
    }

    async getData(sRegion,
                  sCountry,
                  sYear,
                  sSex
    ) {
        const response = await fetch("data.csv");
        const data = await response.text();
        const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);
        const entryName = [];
        const entryValue = [];
        rows.forEach(row => {
            const cols = row.split(',');
            if(this.isSelectableData(cols, sRegion, sCountry, sYear, sSex)) {
                entryName.push(this.getFields(cols));
                entryValue.push(parseFloat(cols[4]));
            }
        });
        return { enName: entryName, enValue: entryValue };
    }

    isSelectableData(cols,
                     sRegion,
                     sCountry,
                     sYear,
                     sSex
    ) {
        return (sRegion.includes(cols[chartData.columnRegion]) || sRegion.length === 0) &&
            (sCountry.includes(cols[chartData.columnCountry]) || sCountry.length === 0) &&
            (sYear.includes(cols[chartData.columnYear]) || sYear.length === 0) &&
            (sSex.includes(cols[chartData.columnSex]) || sSex.length === 0);
    }

    getFields(cols) {
        let fieldsToGet = [chartData.columnCountry, chartData.columnYear, chartData.columnSex]
        let concatenatedValue = ""
        fieldsToGet.forEach(field => {
            concatenatedValue = concatenatedValue + cols[field] + " "
        })
        return concatenatedValue
    }

    updateField(
        fieldColumn,
        optionsID
    ) {
        let options = document.querySelector('#' + optionsID)
        switch(fieldColumn) {
            case chartData.columnRegion:
                chartData.selectedRegion = options.valueOf().value
                this.setCookie(optionsID, chartData.selectedRegion, 7)
                break;
            case chartData.columnCountry:
                chartData.selectedCountry = options.valueOf().value
                this.setCookie(optionsID, chartData.selectedCountry, 7)
                break;
            case chartData.columnYear:
                chartData.selectedYear = options.valueOf().value
                this.setCookie(optionsID, chartData.selectedYear, 7)
                break;
            case chartData.columnSex:
                chartData.selectedSex = options.valueOf().value
                this.setCookie(optionsID, chartData.selectedSex, 7)
                break;
            default:
                console.log("???")
        }
    }

    setCookie(name, value, days) {
        let expires = "";
        if (days) {
            let date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    async getSuggestionsForColumn(fieldColumn) {
        const response = await fetch(misc.dataFileName)
        const data = await response.text()
        let fields = []
        const rows = data.split('\n').slice(1)
        rows.forEach(row =>{
            const cols = row.split(',');
            fields.push(cols[fieldColumn])
        })
        fields = this.RemoveDuplicates(fields)
        console.log(fields)
        return fields
    }

    RemoveDuplicates(arr) {
        let s = new Set(arr);
        let it = s.values();
        return Array.from(it);
    }

    filter() {
        this.updateField(chartData.columnRegion, chartData.idRegion)
        this.updateField(chartData.columnCountry, chartData.idCountry)
        this.updateField(chartData.columnYear, chartData.idYear)
        this.updateField(chartData.columnSex, chartData.idSex)
        viewHandler.refreshChart()
    }

}

/**
 * View
 * Updates the UI
 */

class ViewHandler {

    updateDataFromCookies() {
        chartData.selectedRegion = this.getValueFromCookie(chartData.idRegion)
        chartData.selectedCountry = this.getValueFromCookie(chartData.idCountry)
        chartData.selectedSex = this.getValueFromCookie(chartData.idSex)
        chartData.selectedYear = this.getValueFromCookie(chartData.idYear)
    }

    async generateChart(chartID) {
        const ctx = document.getElementById(chartID).getContext('2d');
        const data = await chartHandler.getData(
            chartData.selectedRegion,
            chartData.selectedCountry,
            chartData.selectedYear,
            chartData.selectedSex
        );
        window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: data.enName,
                datasets: [
                    { //https://jsfiddle.net/flivni/Lcnj1e5x/
                        label: 'Average obesity percentage',
                        data: data.enValue,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: colorManager.getXColors(data.enName.length, colorManager.iterateBorderColorsAndIncrement, colorManager),
                        backgroundColor: colorManager.getXColors(data.enName.length, colorManager.iterateColorsAndIncrement, colorManager),
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {}
        });
    }

    refreshChart() {
        if(window.myChart != null) {
            window.myChart.destroy()
        }
        this.generateChart(misc.mainChartNameId)
    }

    getCookie(name) {
        try {
            return document.cookie.split('; ')
                .find(row => row.startsWith(name + '='))
                .split('=')[1]
        } catch (error) {
            return ""
        }
    }

    getValueFromCookie(name) {
        return this.getCookie(name).split("%2C")
    }

    updateUIValueFromCookie(optionsID) {
        let options = document.getElementById(optionsID)
        let cookieValues = this.getValueFromCookie(optionsID)
        if(cookieValues.length !== 0) {
            options.valueOf().value = this.getValueFromCookie(optionsID)
        }
        // console.log(options.valueOf().value)
        // does not update the UI though... ?
    }

}

/**
 * Model
 */
const chartData = new ChartData()
const colorManager = new ColorManager()
const misc = new Miscellaneous()

/**
 * Controller
 */
const chartHandler = new ChartHandler()

/**
 * View
 */

const viewHandler = new ViewHandler()
```

Comment: I see no PHP here. [The `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) will let you disable an input.

Comment: @miken32 that will only disable it in the frontend. He would need to reject the form input in his backend code.

Comment: Please include your backend code.

Comment: Yes, Mohamed is right! I edited the description a lil bit in order to make it clear. I hope it helps in a way or other. I really want to understand how to code this.

Comment: @showdev, I added it!

Answer (score -1):

This answer is assuming you're using PHP as a backend.

**Backend**

You could make a field in your database that holds a boolean value. If the boolean is set to false it means the user can fill in the form and if the boolean is set to true, the user will not be able to fill in the form.

So how could you do this?

First of all, whenever you disable the input in your admin panel you should send a query to your database that sets the field to a boolean value. We could make a column with the name `field_is_blocked`. So whenever you want to block the form input you update the value of the column to `true`. Otherwise, you set it to `true` or leave it on `true` (you could set the column's default value, so it's true by default).

Whenever the user submits their form you send a query to the database to check if the user is allowed to fill in the input. If they're not allowed, you simply ignore the input.

**Front-end**

On the frontend, you could just set the disabled attribute on the input field
an example:

```
<input type="text" <?php if($isDisabled) echo "disabled"; ?>>
```

`$isDisabled` would be the value you get from the database.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will try this approach!